# TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'bytes' : complement of a string of bytes

Tags: python, string, byte, bitwise-operators

I am trying to compute the complement of this bytes string:

```
bts = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01'
```

I have tried using the tilde `~bts` but I've got a  `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'bytes'`.

I have also tried to use

```
import bitarray
~bitarray.bitarray(bts)
```

It seems to work but later I have to convert it to a bytes string again. So the only solution I came up with is the following:

```
bts2 = bytes([0 if b == 1 else 1 for b in bts])
```

Is there a better alternative to compute the complement?

Comment: Doesn't the `tobytes()` method do what you want to convert it back to a byte string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xor(^)` operator too. the truth table of xor shown below:

```
x    y  |  q
0    0  |  0 
0    1  |  1 
1    0  |  1 
1    1  |  0
```

xor has 2 features: first  `a^1 = ~a` and second  `a^0 =  a` so if you xor 1 on a bit it will be reversed.
in python we can do this in several ways:

```
bytes(x^1 for x in bts)
```

or

```
bytes(map(lambda x:x^1, bts))
```

also you can `not` the `n`th bit in a byte with this code:

```
bytes(x^(1<<n) for x in bts)
```

for one bit in a byte you can use `subtraction` too:

```
bytes(1-x for x in bts)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot can you explain a little bit how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Use `tobytes()` to convert the `bitarray` back to `bytes`.

```
(~bitarray.bitarray(bts)).tobytes()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `not`?

```
>>> bytes(not b for b in bts)
b'\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00'
```

(Same result as your working version)